# Unable to store image in mysql database. NullPointerException

Tags: database, jsp, blob

```
<body>
<form name="frm" action="saveImage.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 <input type="file" name="uProperty" /> <br>
 <input type="submit" name="goUpload" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>

Above is my html code.

<%
Connection conn=null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rs=null;
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/amber";
FileInputStream fis=null;

String myloc=request.getParameter("pic"); 
out.print("mylocation="+myloc);
File image= new File(myloc);
out.println(image);

try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "sameer0207");


pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into image(image) " + "values(?)");

fis=new FileInputStream(image);

pstmt.setBinaryStream(1,fis, image.length());
int count = pstmt.executeUpdate();
if(count>0)
{
out.println("insert successfully");
}
else
{
out.println("not successfully");
}
}catch(Exception e){}

%>
```

This is my jsp file in which i am trying to store value image in database mysql.
The error is in line "File image= new File(myloc);" which browser is showing.
When i print the address only file name is comming not the full address.
when i put address in "File image= new File("C:\images\1.png");"like that it runs correctly.
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String myloc=request.getParameter("pic"); //assumed that  your file object name is "pic" on html page
if (myloc == null) {
  throw new NullPointerException("Source must not be null");  
  if (!Files.exists(myloc)) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Source '" + myloc + "' does not exist");
    out.print("mylocation="+myloc);
    File image= new File(myloc);
    out.println(image);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to add null checking at least because `new File(null);` always throws NPE, for example:

```
if(myloc != null) {
    File f = new File(myloc);
    if (f.exists()) {
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you need use bit32 for image to store image in database.
To store image in database first you need to convert into bit32 and then store in database.
same process is for display from database. i.e.convert bit32 to image and display it..

Comment: More context for the answer would be helpful. Is the bit32 requirement specific to the database referenced in the question, and if so, why? This would help future readers.